# How to show existance of a unique invariant measure A concrete example

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}\left\{X_{n+1}=X_{n}+b \sqrt{p} \mid X_{n}=x\right\}=e^{-\sqrt{p} X_{n}} \\
\mathbb{P}\left\{X_{n+1}=a X_{n} \mid X_{n}=x\right\}=(1-c)\left(1-e^{-\sqrt{p} X_{n}}\right) \\
\mathbb{P}\left\{X_{n+1}=0 \mid X_{n}=x\right\}=c\left(1-e^{-\sqrt{p} X_{n}}\right)
\end{cases}

Could anyone tell me how to show that the above process has a unique invariant measure for all $a\in (0,1), b\in (0,\infty), c\in [0,1]$?

Comment: From which book is this an exercise? Which chapter? What are the contents of that chapter? You are likely to use tools from there, so telling us this will help us advise you.